# ModuleNotFoundError though PYTHONPATH is set properly

Tags: python, gitlab

Everything seems to be correct but still has an error.
The same code works at my local machine but does not work at GitLab-ci

I wonder if "pip install -r $CI_PROJECT_DIR/scripts/config_creator/requirements.txt" ruins something

**Gitlab-ci stage**

```
Clone Siteconfigs:
  stage: configure-site
  script:
    - echo $PYTHONPATH
    - apt-get update --yes
    - apt-get install --yes  python3-pip
    - python3 --version
    - pip install -r $CI_PROJECT_DIR/scripts/config_creator/requirements.txt
    - echo $PYTHONPATH
    - export PYTHONPATH=$CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - echo $PYTHONPATH
    - python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
    - python3 $CI_PROJECT_DIR/scripts/config_creator/__main__.py create-loadtest-config-file --dataset-uri-list ${LOADTEST_SOURCES_DATASET_URI_LIST}
```

**GitLab-CI Output**

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/builds/qa/load-test-ci
$ python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/builds/qa/load-test-ci', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
$ python3 $CI_PROJECT_DIR/scripts/config_creator/__main__.py create-loadtest-config-file --dataset-uri-list ${LOADTEST_SOURCES_DATASET_URI_LIST}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/builds/qa/load-test-ci/scripts/config_creator/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scripts.config_creator.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.config_creator'
```

****main**.py**

```
from scripts.config_creator.cli.main import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, it is because of a package name "scripts"  comes with after `pip install` After changing `scripts`->`my_scripts` it works.